# How can I limit the size of Apache's access_log, and limit the number of archived logs it keeps?

Tags: logging, apache

Apache's access_log file rotates out into an archived copy around 1GB every few days.  Where are the settings to control this?  I'd like to be able to control both the max size and the number of archived logs it keeps around.  Is this part of apache's configuration, or do I need to write cron jobs ( et al ) to deal with this?  I'm running pre-forked httpd.

Comment: What operating system does your server use?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On most Linux distributions, the system is set up to run **logrotate** on a daily basis. You won't see it in the crontab for root or for any particular user.

It's easy to change how it handles log files. On my Ubuntu server, the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file has settings like these:

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress
```

[etc.]

And, you can look in the directory `/etc/logrotate.d/` to see settings for specific directories and apps.

Comment: What file should I look for to edit the log settings of virtual domains on the server? Would this be `logrotate.d/apache2`?

Comment: that would be inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Answer (score 3):

I would use rotatelogs, a tool located in the apache bin directory.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html for more information and examples. It has the advantage to exist on my HP-UX system.

Or as mentioned previously, you can use the logrotate tool that comes with most distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to control a size of my log files per virtual host and ended up with it:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /var/www/my-virtual-host.com/logs/error_log_%Y.%m.%d.log 10M"
```

Use `which rotatelogs` to find a path of an executable. Im my case it was `/usr/bin/rotatelogs` not |`bin/rotatelogs` as it's described in documentation.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html

Obviously rotatelogs can be applied to access_log (ie. CustomLog) as well.

Comment: On Windows, I can use this command `CustomLog "|${SRVROOT}/bin/rotatelogs.exe ${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log 1M" common` where `${SRVROOT}` is from `Define SRVROOT "C:/wwwserver/apache24"` that was added in main config file. However, the problem is some other log on virtual host did not write out. Maybe because [heap space](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) that was mentioned in their document. The log output is **access.log.nnn** where nnn is timestamp not **access.log** file name.

Answer (score 1):

The other_vhosts_access.log logs were growing too fast and I  commented out the CustomLog line in /etc/apache2/conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The customary way is to run [`logrotate`](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/) from a cronjob, which can slice, dice, compress, rename, keep the last n and most other things one could want. (I think most distributions these days install it by default.)

Comment: What is causing it to rotate out into an archived copy now?  I don't have any cron jobs set.  I do occasionally restart httpd.  Does that do it?